# How can I export a table and import the data to other table?

Tags: java, jdbc

I want to export data from A table and import the data to B table. A and B table are the same tables and they are have 100 columns. How can I export and import within JDBC? I want to do it dynamically. I do not want to write one column to other.(2 tables have same columns. But Table A in oracle and Table B in mysql)
Thank you.

Comment: Quote : "_A and B table are the same tables_", what does that mean ? Otherwise, you can consider creating a java code to retrieve data from a table and insert it into the other table, that will be quite easy in my guess.

Comment: @Gloserio  I mean they have same columns. And I want to export data and insert other table. (bulk copy)

Comment: Have you thought about using some java code (DataSource, Connection, Statement and ResultSet objects) ? Or you looking for an immidiate approach ?

Comment: I use Connection, Statement and ResultSet objects in jdbc.

Comment: Then please do show the code, if it's mistaken or disfunctionnal indicate how so to receive better pointed help. I think the guys are misunderstanding your question.

Comment: @Gloserio  I have 2 different connections.the issue is I dont know how can I  select * from A(oracle connection with jdbc) to insert data B table (mysql connection)

Comment: Well, I am not sure I am getting correctly the point here, but if it's only a matter of accessing the A table in Oracle via a JDBC connection then that's not far from `OracleDataSource ods = new OracleDataSource();
ods.setURL("jdbc:oracle:oci);
ods.setUser("scott");
ods.setPassword("tiger");

Connection conn = ods.getConnection();`

Comment: I can reach each table and I write select * from A; and I get data.
But How can I write that result set the other table ?

Comment: Ok, if the issue is writing down data from one to the other, then you must loop on the "oracle" resultset, retrieve a line and use the "mysql" resultSet to insert data in the B table.

Comment: yep that is the issue. I dont want to write each column. I want to write like insert Table A select resultset. I mean I dont want to write resultset.getstring(1), resultset.getstring(2).. ..,resultset.getstring(100)

Comment: Yes, but you still can use `ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();

        for (int i = 1; i < columnCount + 1; i++) {
            String column = rsmd.getColumnName(i); }` which can get the names of the columns in your A table, this way you'll not have to write down all their names. All you'll have left to do is use this to generate your `select from` String.

Comment: okey thank you @Gloserio I try it and I will update you as soon as possible.

Comment: Posted something, I hope that helps.

Comment: i think this is better as a SQL and database effort than trying to code something in java.  dblinks are the way to go.

Comment: yes it s working but   if I insert 1 million rows it will be very long time and bad performance. How can I insert bulk copy using jdbc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be of help :

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM A");
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();

String insert_string = "INSERT INTO B(" ;
for (int i = 1; i < columnCount + 1; i++) {
     String column = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
     insert_string += column + ", " ;
     }
insert_string += " )"; // Column part of INSERT INTO B should be well formed

insert_string += " VALUES (" ;

int i=0;
while(i < columnCount - 1){
    i++;
    insert_string += "'"+ rs.getString(i)+"', " ;
}

insert_string += "'" + rs.getString(columnCount) + ")" ; // VALUES part should be ok by now
```

This far, we must have a one valid `INSERT` statement, but that's only for one row in the `rs` object. An iteration with `rs.next()` must be included in the code so as to repead the creation of that `INSERT` string for all A rows.

As for the performance, I honestly have no clue. I don't recommend this, but I think it's a fair way of addressing the question.

Comment: yes you are right if I insert 1 million rows it will be very long time and bad performance. How can I insert bulk copy using jdbc?

Comment: Yes, that'll quickly run you in a out of memory sort of exception ! Check out this [link](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/batch-insert-in-java-jdbc/), the last part "batch withing batch" may help you. Still, in the internet it seems that there's no equivalent to bulk insert with JDBC ; hence - and until further notice - , I think you have to suffer to do this programmatically lol.

Comment: Check out this as well : [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784197/efficient-way-to-do-batch-inserts-with-jdbc)

Comment: when I write stmt.executeQuery(insert_string ) ; it returns = A Result Set was expected but not generated from query ;

Comment: Have you used `ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(insert_string)` ?

Comment: that is not working. stmt.addBatch(insert_string);  is working

Comment: Cool, did you finally succeed ?

Comment: I can insert data but it is still slow I do not understand.Because I made batches include 500 insert statament and it inserts 190 rows per second

Comment: So now it works but it's slow ? If that's the case, I think it deserve a question on its own since the issue would clearly be performance, tag that question with DB tags, so people from DB background can help you increase performance.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
insert into tableB
select * from tableA
```

This is possible also if the tables are in different databases, creating a DB-link between the databases (granted you have the permissions to do so).

You can otherwise copy a max number of columns from TableA in memory and than insert them into the TableB, but I strongly discourage this.

Unfortunately in java there is nothing similar to the .NET BulkCopy

Comment: I am using jdbc and table A and table B is in different connection.

Comment: Oh now I see, so you'd like something like bulkcopy in .NET... what sql vendor are you using?

Comment: I use java (netbeans project) with jdbc connections

Comment: I mean, you use MySql, Oracle, SQL Server? Anyway, I suggested in my response to use a dblink. If you have not more than thousands of rows you can also copy data in memory and tranfer them into the other table.