# What is the maximum size of a `String` object in Java?

Tags: java, string

A simple question: What is the maximum size (in bytes or characters) of a `String` object in Java?

Some background info: I want to build a SQL statement (`INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (...), (...), ...`) and I don't want to exceed the size of the object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strings contain an array of chars, so I think you can have at most `2^31 - 1` characters in a Java String.  This is the value of `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Any String larger than that, and you can't even index all of the elements.

Comment: Assuming you have sufficient memory available.

Comment: That one String would be roughly 4GB if I did the math correctly.

Answer (score 3):

from the source code

```
class String implements java.io.Serializable {
    private char value[]; // 4 bytes + 12 bytes of array header
    private int offset; // 4 bytes
    private int count; // 4 bytes
}
```

what ever the value of  Integer.MAX_VALUE is (which on most systems will be `2^31 -1`)

this requires 4GB of memory though so its a very large amount (java uses 16 bit unicode)

so the minimum of Integer.MAX_VALUE and the available memory

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to insert many rows.  Use a `PreparedStatement` and batch parameters.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/3786127/1172714.

Please note that assembling a SQL statement as a `String` is a dangerous practice. Instead use a prepared statement http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: Thank you. I know it can be dangerous, but this specific program is for my personal use, and I can take the luxury of being "not so formal" ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically it could be Integer.MAX_VALUE chars long.