# Java adding a list to database

Tags: java, sql

So I have a Product.java class:

```
Public class Product{
private String id;
private String name;
private float price;
}
```

I have a list of Product that get data from database:

```
public List<Product> getProductList() {
    List<Product> list = new ArrayList<Product>();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM Product";
    try {
        Statement st = getConnection().createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next()) {
            String id = rs.getString(1);
            String name = rs.getString(3);
            float price = rs.getFloat(4);
            Product p = new Product();
            p.setId(id);
            p.setName(name);
            p.setPrice(price);
            list.add(p);
        }
        rs.close();
        st.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DataProcess.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return list;
}
```

I add some Product to another list, and now I want to add that list back to database into table Sold, but I only know how to add a Product items to database, not the whole list. Is there a way to add a list to database?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with **PreparedStatement**'s **addBatch()** and **executeBatch()** methods as this other answer demonstrates:

> This is a mix of the two previous answers:
>
> ```
>   PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO employees VALUES (?, ?)");
>
>   ps.setString(1, "John");
>   ps.setString(2,"Doe");
>   ps.addBatch();
>
>   ps.clearParameters();
>   ps.setString(1, "Dave");
>   ps.setString(2,"Smith");
>   ps.addBatch();
>
>   ps.clearParameters();
>   int[] results = ps.executeBatch();
> ```

SOURCE: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3786127

In your case you would set the necessary parameters and then call **addBatch()** on each iteration of a loop over the list and then after the loop call **executeBatch()**.

You may want to call **executeBatch()** inside the loop after a certain number of items if the database places limits on batches and doesnmt handle those limits transaparently in its JDBC driver.