# How can i insert data using procedure sql?

Tags: java, postgresql, stored-procedures, jdbc

Today I have trouble to insert data into Postgres database using procedure. I have one procedure to insert record to it , but it is so slow with many record. Can help to fix my procedure.

```
void insertRecord(ArrayList<Product> pro)throws Exception{
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/dbStock?","rina","2001");
        //con.setAutoCommit(false);

        CallableStatement stmt=con.prepareCall("{call MyInsert(?,?,?,?,?)}");

        for(Product p:pro){
            stmt.setInt(1, p.getId());
            stmt.setString(2, p.getName());
            stmt.setInt(3, p.getUnitprice());
            stmt.setInt(4, p.getQty());
            stmt.setString(5, p.getImportedDate());
            //pstm.executeUpdate();
            stmt.execute();
        }
        //con.commit();
    }


//main Method
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
            ArrayList<Product>pro=new ArrayList<>();
            for(int i=1;i<=1_00000;i++){
                pro.add(new Product(i,"coca",12,12,"2014"));
            }
            System.out.println("Done");
            Long start=System.currentTimeMillis();
            new dbObjectDriver().insertRecord(pro);
            long stop=System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println(stop-start);
        }
```

Comment: see this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784197/efficient-way-to-do-batch-inserts-with-jdbc for batch insert.

Comment: why do you need a stored procedure for that?

Comment: yes you should indeed consider using a batch insert

Comment: also whatever you're doing in your procdure make sure theres no unnecessary full table scans in your queries. That can have an impact at higher volumes

Comment: i am not clear about addbatch