# Azure SQL JDBC Use Bulk Insert

Tags: java, azure, azure-sql-database

I am going through this [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/use-bulk-copy-api-batch-insert-operation?view=sql-server-ver16), to improve the performance of my insert query in Azure SQL, it says  Bulk Copy API does not support `Date` field is there any way via which i can improve my inserts in Azure SQL. I heavy write requirements.

Below is the code i am using:

```
   public void saveAllJdbc(List<JdbcDetail> jdbcDetails){

       String sql = String.format("INSERT INTO %s  VALUES (?, ?, ?,?)", "my-table");

       try (Connection connection = hikariDataSource.getConnection();
             PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        ){
            int counter = 0;

            for (JdbcDetail row : jdbcDetails) {
                statement.clearParameters();
                statement.setInt(1, row.getQuantity());
                statement.setDate(2, Date.valueOf(row.getDate()));
                statement.setFloat(3, row.getId());
                statement.setInt(4, row.getNum());
              
                statement.addBatch();
                if ((counter + 1) % 10000 == 0) {
                   statement.executeBatch();
                  statement.clearBatch();
                }

                counter++;
            }

       } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You almost checked all options by using parameterized query as well connection pooling so there could be two more things you can check , one is just look for a right batch size by experimenting the batch size and second thing by default JDBC commit each individual statement. you can disable that auto commit and they give it a try. Thanks also you can look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784197/efficient-way-to-do-batch-inserts-with-jdbc