# How to bulk update multiple rows at a time with different matching conditions?

Tags: sql

I have a large dataset with the following columns

```
id,
token1,
token2,
token4,
record
```

Now someone gave me a list of changes to be done to this table.

if `token1 = xxx and token2 = yyy and token4 = zzz`  change record to some another value `kkk`

like this i have another 100k changes need to be done.

so they have given a csv file as

```
token1,token2,token4,record
xxxx,yyy,zzzz,kkk..
...
100K changes
```

Whats the best way to deal in this situation

My plan is

- create a for loop in python
- loop through each line in the csv file,
- check if record exists then change the recordid to the corresponding recordid mentioned.

Can someone suggest whats the best way to do a bulk update with multiple where conditions.

I have to do this task on snowflake

Comment: Are the values for token1, token2, etc. Different for each row? Or do you need to update the same values for each row?

Comment: This question is tagged as sql but does not mention which database platform - sqlserver, mysql or oracle? If you are supposed to use python code to update then you should use python tag as well. Also you can try posting on https://dba.stackexchange.com if you are interested about database performance / pagelock

Comment: If using Java is an option, then [JDBC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html) supports [batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784197/efficient-way-to-do-batch-inserts-with-jdbc) operations. There are also third-party libraries for handling CSV files such as [OpenCSV](https://www.baeldung.com/opencsv).

Comment: It's going to take a long time to loop through that many records using any method. https://sqlstudies.com/2016/08/17/rbar-vs-batch/ It will be much quicker to import the  changes to a local table in the database then run one `update` query.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: @MonishB  the token1, token2 values are different for each row. The values to be updated for each row will be different.

Comment: @Rakib  its snowflake related

Comment: Then I think you'll need to use it with cases! Not sure though. @Santhosh