Batch Scripting in Nifi through Custom Groovy Script
I want to fetch the flowfiles from the input stream in bulk and create the one bulk insertion query for Clickhouse.
I am currently creating the the one insertion query for each document of mongoDB. Here is following code for this:
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import org.apache.nifi.processor.io.StreamCallback
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils

class GenerateInsertQuery implements StreamCallback {

    // Convert MongoDB date string to ClickHouse-compatible DateTime format
    String toClickhouseDateFormat(String mongoDate) {
        if (!mongoDate) return null

        def parsedDate = null
        def formats = ["yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"]

        formats.each { format ->
            try {
                parsedDate = Date.parse(format, mongoDate)
                return
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }

        // If none of the formats match, return null
        return parsedDate != null ? parsedDate.format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") : null
    }

    // Sanitize value for SQL
    String sanitizeValue(String value) {
        if (value == null || value.trim().isEmpty() || value == '') return null
        return value.replace("'", "''")
    }

    @Override
    void process(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream) {
        // Read the JSON content from the FlowFile
        def json_content = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
        def json_object = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json_content)

        // Extract and sanitize values, using null-safe operator
        def id_value = sanitizeValue(json_object?._id?.'$oid')
        def first_name = sanitizeValue(json_object?.first_name)
        def last_name = sanitizeValue(json_object?.last_name)

        // Create the SQL INSERT query
        def insert_query = """INSERT INTO db.table_name (comma separated columns names)
                            VALUES (
                            ${id_value != null ? "'${id_value}'" : null},
                            ${first_name != null ? "'${first_name}'" : null},
                            ${last_name != null ? "'${last_name}'" : null}
                        );"""

        // Write the SQL query back to the FlowFile
        outputStream.write(insert_query.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
    }
}

// Apply the StreamCallback to modify the FlowFile content
flowFile = session.get()
if (flowFile) {
    try {
        flowFile = session.write(flowFile, new GenerateInsertQuery())
        session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Handle any errors by transferring to the failure relationship
        session.transfer(flowFile, REL_FAILURE)
    }
} else {
    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_FAILURE)
}

How can I make this script for nifi to make the bulk insertion query?. If anyone knows kindly create that script for me by modifying this script.

what processor you are using to write mongodb?

it's not clear why you are producing INSERT INTO .... are you using kind of jdbc driver for mongobd?

Yes I am using the JDBC driver for mongodb. @daggett

it will really depend on JDBC driver that you are using because mongodb is not supporting SQL natively. so, read documentation of JDBC driver. that's how code could look like for bulk insert using jdbc driver: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3786127
If your jdbc driver supports addBatch and executeBatch functions - i can give you a snippet for your case.
